# Як перекласти "easing function"?

Tags: from-english, resource-request

Мене цікавить максимально коректний технічний переклад.
Контекст у якому вживається: `This formula can be used in CSS easing functions`.

У цій локалізації використовують переклад "функція пом'якшення": https://easings.net/uk.
Проте мене насторожило, що терміну "функція пом'якшення" немає у вікіпедії, а це мав би бути усталений математичний термін.

Comment: Але ж _easing function_ теж [немає](//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=easing+function) в (англійській) вікіпедії. По-моєму, _функція пом'якшення_ — цілком прийнятний варіант (можливо, є кращі, але й цей здається прийнятним).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так розумію, що поняття [easing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function) ввели, бо не всі функції, що показують як параметр змінюється з часом, [гладкі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F). Наприклад, негладка (недиференційовна) ліворуч і гладка (нескінченно диференційовна) праворуч:

[image]

Також існують супутні терміни *ease-in* (синя), *ease-out* (фіолетова), *ease-in-out* (праворуч згори).

[image]

Отже треба шукати переклад, який для всіх цих термінів одразу.

Як на мене *функція пом'якшування* відповідає всім вимогам.

Comment: Дякую за математику, тепер знатиму, що цей термін стосується гладких функцій.

Comment: @Yola До речі, до "гладка" більше підходить "згладжування", і це слово інтуїтивно підходить до лівого графіка "недиференційовної" функції. Але тоді б англійською було "smoothing", а не "easing" :)

Comment: @Olha ну, власне, так, бо до *функції пом'якшування*, якщо ми погоджуємось на цей термін, нема вимоги бути *гладкою*. Вона може бути, наприклад, як сходинки.

Comment: А, я зрозумів… Тобто інакше назвали б _smoothing functions_ (_функції згладжування_), але оскільки не всі такі функції гладкі, то автори стандарту придумали новий термін? (Бо я, якщо чесно, спочатку навіть не втелепав був, чому мова пішла про гладкість.)

Comment: Перепрошую, але цей термін означає будь-яку функцію, перша похідна якої дорівнює нулю на початку `f'(x₀)=0` (ease-in) або у кінці `f'(xₙ)=0`(ease-out) області визначення. Або і те, і інше (ease-in-out). На відміну від лінійної транспозиції, в якої `f'(x) = C`. Диференційовність тут ні до чого.

Comment: @bytebuster а ви говорите про термін *гладка* чи *easing*? Я вжив диференційовність щодо гладка.

Comment: @Yola, ваша відповідь про диференційовність (=гладкість). Мій коментар про easing. Але це не одне і те саме.

Comment: @bytebuster відповідь стверджує, що термін easing взяли тому, що не могли взяти smoothing, бо не всі такі функції гладкі (диференційовні).

Comment: @Sasha саме таке моє припущення. Хоча в анімації ця назва з'явилась до CSS. Тобто, коли ти робиш покрокову анімацію, то ти спочатку рухаєш людинку повільно, потім швидше - ease in.